# How add my uwp app on DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI()

Tags: c#, uwp

I would like to add my uwp app to be displayed on the DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI() screen of another app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to add my uwp app to be displayed on the DataTransferManager

If you want to show your app's icon in the share ui, you need to declare your app as a share target.
Please refer the following steps

1. Open the manifest file. It should be called something like package.appxmanifest.
2. Open the Declarations tab.
3. Choose Share Target from the Available Declarations list, and then select Add.

For more info please refer [Receive data document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/receive-data#declare-your-app-as-a-share-target). And this is official [code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/sharetarget/) that your could refer to.